# What is the authentic hadith about reciting 1000 ayats of Qur'an in Qiyaam?

Tags: hadith, source-identification, ibadah

Recently, I heard the imam of a masjid say that they're planning to plow through 1000 ayaat of Qur'an during a certain night of laylatu-al-qadar because of a hadith that specifically mentions reciting 1000 verses with a certain reward.

I didn't get a chance to ask him which hadith it is. I couldn't find it when I searched online. What hadith is he probably alluding to?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is the hadith you are looking for:

> Narrated Abdullah ibn Amr ibn al-'As:
>
> The Prophet (sallallahu 'alaihi wa sallam) said: If anyone prays at
>   night reciting regularly ten verses, he will not be recorded among the
>   negligent; if anyone prays at night and recites a hundred verses, he
>   will be recorded among those who are obedient to Allah; and if anyone
>   prays at night reciting one thousand verses, he will be recorded among
>   those who receive huge rewards.
>
> Abu Dawud said: The name of Ibn Hujairah al-Asghar is 'Abd Allah b.
>   'Abd al-Rahman b. Hujairah.
>
> حَدَّثَنَا أَحْمَدُ بْنُ صَالِحٍ، حَدَّثَنَا ابْنُ وَهْبٍ، أَخْبَرَنَا
>   عَمْرٌو، أَنَّ أَبَا سَوِيَّةَ، حَدَّثَهُ أَنَّهُ، سَمِعَ ابْنَ
>   حُجَيْرَةَ، يُخْبِرُ عَنْ عَبْدِ اللَّهِ بْنِ عَمْرِو بْنِ الْعَاصِ،
>   قَالَ قَالَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم ‏ "‏ مَنْ قَامَ
>   بِعَشْرِ آيَاتٍ لَمْ يُكْتَبْ مِنَ الْغَافِلِينَ وَمَنْ قَامَ
>   بِمِائَةِ آيَةٍ كُتِبَ مِنَ الْقَانِتِينَ وَمَنْ قَامَ بِأَلْفِ آيَةٍ
>   كُتِبَ مِنَ الْمُقَنْطَرِينَ ‏"‏ ‏.‏ قَالَ أَبُو دَاوُدَ ابْنُ
>   حُجَيْرَةَ الأَصْغَرُ عَبْدُ اللَّهِ بْنُ عَبْدِ الرَّحْمَنِ بْنِ
>   حُجَيْرَةَ ‏.‏
>
> [Sunan Abi Dawood](http://sunnah.com/abudawud/6/28)

It is graded as Sahih (authentic) by Sheikh Nasiruddin Al Albani.